# GROUP BY, value could be in either of 2 columns

Tags: sql, count, group-by

Ok, I'm really not sure how to tackle this SQL problem so I'll just go ahead and explain it...

I have a table with the following columns :

```
gameId, winnerPlayerId, winnerFactionId, loserPlayerId, loserFactionId
```

Now, I'd like to build a query that, given a factionId, outputs the following data :

```
playerId, totalGamesPlayedAsFaction
```

What stumps me here, is that I each row in the table needs to be counted TWICE, once for the loser and once for the winner... Therefore I can't use a simple GROUP BY winnerPlayerId.

I feel as if my question is not particularly clear and that the solution is probably quite simple...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "duplicate" the data somehow.  The most typical way would use `union all`:

```
select . . .
from ((select gameId, winnerPlayerId as PlayerId, winnerFactionId as FactionId
       from table t
      ) union all
      (select gameId, loserPlayerId as PlayerId, loserFactionId as FactionId
       from table t
      )
     ) t
group by PlayerId, FactionId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for the ever popular self join

```
select playerid, count(*) total
from player p left join game winner on p.playerid = winner.winnerplayerid
left join game loser on p.playerid = loser.loserplayerid
etc
```

This will get you started.  You'll have to contend with filters and null values on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The glamorous and multi-purpose way would be to do an unpivot of sorts, but the quick and dirty way is similar to the union all method.  The full SQL for that would be:

```
select games.PlayerId, COUNT(games.gameId)
from ((select gameId, winnerPlayerId as PlayerId, winnerFactionId as FactionId
       from tblGame winners
       ) 
      union all
       (select gameId, loserPlayerId as PlayerId, loserFactionId as FactionId
       from tblGame losers
        )
     ) games
where games.FactionId = 'x'
group by games.PlayerId
```